# How to resize the image before saving to server for Node JS. (multer itself, gm) I am open to any option

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image-processing

I tried to include image resizing before posting. Multer is used to receiving photos. Then, after using input all information including photos.
I would like to reduce the size and quality of image before they post. However, it's doesn't work. Anyone can giving suggestion?

```
const multer = require('multer');                
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'photo')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'car-' + Date.now() + '.png')
    },
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
const gm = require('gm');

module.exports = (app,passport) => {
    app.post('/sell', isLoggedIn, upload.any(), (req,res,next) => {
        gm(req.files)
            .resize(250, 250)
            .gravity('Center')
            .extent(width, height)
            .noProfile()
            .write('/photo/' + req.file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
        async.waterfall([
            function(callback) {
                var newCar = new Car();
                newCar.owner = req.user._id;
                newCar.make = req.body.make;
                newCar.model = req.body.model;
                newCar.year = req.body.year;
                newCar.mileage = req.body.mileage;
                newCar.price = req.body.price;
                newCar.detail = req.body.detail;
                newCar.locationProvince = req.body.locationProvince;
                newCar.locationDistrict = req.body.locationDistrict;
                //newCar.image = req.files; 
                newCar.save((err) => {
                    callback(err, newCar);
                });
            },
            function (newCar, callback) {
                User.update (
                    {
                        _id: req.user._id
                    },{
                        $push: {cars: newCar._id }
                    }, function (err,count) {
                        req.flash('success', 'success')
                        res.redirect('/')
                    }
                )
            }
        ]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please specifies error or something more about your problem. I think you need to console.log -> res.files, it could be an array. Also, check your path in write if it's correct. And the last one, probably you don't add callback function -> write(path, cb).

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it now. But, I don't know how to save the image which have been resized to mongoose.

```
app.post('/sell', isLoggedIn, upload.any(), (req, res, next) => {
        async.waterfall([
          function(callback) {
            console.log('files', req.files)

            if (req.files.length > 0) {
              req.files.map(function(file) {
                var x = gm(file.path)
                  .resize(800, 640)
                  .gravity('Center')
                  //.extent(250, 250)
                  .noProfile()
                  .quality(80)
                  .write('./photo/resized/' + file.filename +'-800x640', function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log('error : ', err)
                    }
                    console.log(file.filename + ' resized!')
                  });
              })


                //console.log(req.files.path)
                //console.log(req.files)
                var newCar = new Car();
                newCar.owner = req.user._id;
                newCar.make = req.body.make;
                newCar.model = req.body.model;
                newCar.year = req.body.year;
                newCar.mileage = req.body.mileage;
                newCar.price = req.body.price;
                newCar.detail = req.body.detail;
                newCar.locationProvince = req.body.locationProvince;
                newCar.locationDistrict = req.body.locationDistrict;
                newCar.image = req.files; 
                newCar.image_resized = x; 
                newCar.save((err) => {
                    callback(err, newCar);
                });
                }
            },
```